# Why instance variables are not initialized before constructor creation. What happens if they are initialized at the class loading itself

Tags: java, c#

As we know Constructor purpose is to initialize instance variables, what if they are initialized before itself...does that effect the code..

Comment: C# or JAVA? Because they handle initialization of members pretty different. Please provide a short sample of what exactly you´re asking.

Comment: "what if they are initialized before itself" [in Java] they're not. When initializers are specified on fields, those initializers are inlined into the constructor by the compiler.

Comment: they can't be, since they belong to a specific instance, hence the name: instance variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5):

Well aside languages differences, of course yes it affects code.

For instance you could have more constructors. If you init a field online, it would be ALWAYS with a value.

If you do it in a constructor, maybe you could decide there is no need in another constructor.

In generale inline init comes before constructor, so a constructor could override it, for instance in java :

```
package test;

public class Test {

    private String field1 = "INLINE";

    public Test() {
        System.out.println( "field1 value "+this.field1 );
        this.field1 = "CONSTRUCTOR";
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println( t.getField1() );
    }

}
```

The result would be

```
field1 value INLINE
CONSTRUCTOR
```